# Error installing homebrew in Apple M2 MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, cocoapods, homebrew, apple-m1, apple-silicon

I am trying to install the HomeBrew on my AppleM2 MacBook Pro 16GB / 256SSD

Step1: Download and install the Xcode 14.2

Step2: Download and install the Command Line Tools for Xcode 14.2.dmg file from the developer's site, i.e https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Step3: I am trying to run the below command to install the homebrew in my MacBook Pro M2

/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"

Step4: Then I am facing the below ERROR
curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 75223 ms: Operation timed out.

I am not able to install cocoapods without fixing this home-brew installation error.

System Info:
MacBook Pro M2,
macOS Ventura 13.1,
Xcode 14.2,
Xcode command line tools 14.2.

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am just changed my Internet connection and then I am tried then its working fine.

Cause: Due to low bandwidth / low service of my current internet provider.